# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android

I know there a lot of answers for this question relatively, but none of them has helped me in resolving my problem.

My App starts up and runs fine, but when i open it after leaving it running for a while it crashes and gives the exception seen above, please help me fix this, thanks in advance.

Find errors given below. Errors:(2 major errors in total)

- android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
- Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@223058cf: Unmarshalling unknown type code 28 at offset 1708

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    UiUtils.setPreferenceTheme(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Here's the logcat:

```
04-11 18:14:14.617 669-685/net.sammytech.cakes I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 390(36KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 62% free, 9MB/25MB, paused 7.370ms total 34.287ms
```

04-11 18:14:14.622 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
04-11 18:14:14.622 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
04-11 18:14:14.667 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-11 18:14:14.717 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime: Process: net.sammytech.cakes, PID: 669
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.sammytech.cakes/nl.platinum.madivashairstyles.activity.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at nl.platinum.madivashairstyles.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:193)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@223058cf: Unmarshalling unknown type code 28 at offset 1708
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2222)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2540)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1868)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2203)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:871)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:836)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1060)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2156)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5636)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at nl.platinum.madivashairstyles.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:193) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
04-11 18:14:14.722 669-669/net.sammytech.cakes E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Activity_main XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout">

    <include layout="@layout/view_home"/>

    <include layout="@layout/view_left_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```